# undefined C/C++ symbol as operator

Tags: c++, c, syntax, operators, symbols

I notice that the character/symbol '`' and '@' is not used as an operator in C/C++,

1. does anyone know the reason or historically why its so?
2. if its really not used, is it safe to define those symbols as another operator/statement using #define?

Comment: Note that `@` is used extensively in Objective-C (a superset of C).

Comment: i'am asking strictly on C or C++ not another derivative or superset, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally, `#define` only accepts valid identifiers in the macro name - so you cannot do:

```
#define @      at
#define @(x)   [x]
```

Similarly with back-quote.  And you didn't mention '$', which is sometimes allowed in identifiers.

There might be a compiler-specific extension to allow such mappings, but I wouldn't use it.

---

As to the historical reason for this, there are parts of the [ISO 646](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646) character set that are reserved to national implementations for national characters.  These reserved portions include the characters that cause trouble, and the trigraphs and digraphs features in Standard C (and hence Standard C++) were added to ISO C in 1989 and 1994 respectively to provide workarounds for the problems.

#### Trigraphs

Trigraphs were added during the C89 standardization process to prevent people from, for example, having to see alphabetic characters (in Scandinavian languages) used in their C code (adapted from an example in B Stroustrup, 'Design and Evolution of C++', using a Danish terminal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argvÆÅ)
æ
    if (argc < 1 øø *argvÆ1Å == 'Ø0') return 0;
    printf("Hello, %sØn", argvÆ1Å);
å
```

Or, in the ISO 8859-1 code set (or any of the ISO 8859-x code sets):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
     if (argc < 1 || argv[1] == '\0') return 0;
     printf("Hello, %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

The trigraphs were introduced to produce a neutral format for the code:

```
??=include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv??(??))
??<
    if (argc < 1 ??!??! *argv??(1??) == '??/0') return 0;
    printf("Hello, %s??/n", argv??(1??));
??>
```

That's not very readable, either, but it is the same for everyone.

```
Trigraph      Equivalent to
??/           \      backslash
??<           {      open brace
??>           }      close brace
??(           [      open square bracket
??)           ]      close square bracket
??=           #      hash (pound in American, but a pound is £ in English)
??'           ^      caret
??!           |      pipe
??-           ~      tilde
```

The standard says 'there are no other trigraphs'.  This is why the escape sequence '\?' is recognized (as a simple question mark - though presumably that is '??/?').  Note that the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) does not interpret trigraphs unless you hold its hand to the fire (specify '`-trigraphs`' on the command line).

#### Digraphs

The digraphs were added in 1994, and are not as pervasive or intrusive as trigraphs; they only appear outside strings and string literals.  The digraphs are:

```
Digraph       Equivalent to
<:            [
:>            ]
<%            {
%>            }
%:            #
%:%:          ##
```

The example using digraphs (and trigraphs):

```
%:include <stdio.h>
%:include <iso646.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv<::>)
<%
    if (argc < 1 or *argv<:1:> == '??/0') return 0;
    printf("Hello, %s??/n", argv<:1:>);
%>
```

#### At sign and back quote specifically?

If you look at the Wikipedia URL above, you'll see that both '@' and '`' are sometimes replaced by national characters - and hence not good identifiers.  An additional reason for not using '@' is that at the time C was introduced, '#" was the default erase character and '@' was the kill (line erase) character for terminals.  So, you had to remember to escape them.  Since '#' only appeared at the beginning of a line, it wasn't too much of a problem (using '#' and '##' came much, much later - standardization again), but '@' would have wiped out all the preceding typing on the line.  And this is the days before 'vi' - 'ed is the the standard Unix editor'.

Comment: Good catch on `$` -- it's allowed in identifiers by GCC on most platforms, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably safe, but it's almost definitely a really bad idea. Since `@` is not a standard operator, *anyone else* else reading your code will have to go track down the definition of `@` wherever you use it. We name functions and don't just use symbols so that humans reading the code can figure out what it does.

On a side note, Objective-C uses `@`. Not sure if that's relevant to your project, but if anyone tried to use your C code from ObjC, all their code would break because of your `#define`.

Comment: so in other word, i could prevent my codes for being linked using Objective-C by using @ symbol right?...

Comment: @uray: No. The ObjC users could just use a self-made header file.

Comment: Sure, you could prevent your codes from being used in Objective-C, but they wouldn't be valid C either.  *Every* valid C program is a valid Objective-C program.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to C:

A `#define`d macro has a name that is a C identifier (§6.10).

An identifier may consist of `_a-zA-Z0-9` (§6.4.2.1).  Anything else is implementation-defined.  If you use `@` in a macro name, it may work on some compilers (though I would be surprised), but it will not be portable.

I don't know what the situation is with C++.

Comment: Basically, in this context, C and C++ are the same as far as standard identifiers go.