# Why is "\?" an escape sequence in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, escaping

There are four special non-alphabet characters that need to be escaped in C/C++: the single quote `\'`, the double quote `\"`, the backslash `\\`, and the question mark `\?`. It's apparently because they have special meanings. `'` for single `char`, `"` for string literals, `\` for escape sequences, but why is `?` one of them?

I read the table of escape sequences in a textbook today and I realized that I've **never** escaped `?` before and have never encountered a problem with it. Just to be sure, I tested it under GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("question mark ? and escaped \?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And the C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "question mark ? and escaped \?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both programs output:  `question mark ? and escaped ?`

So I have two questions:

1. Why is `\?` one of the escape sequence characters?
2. Why does non-escaping `?` work fine? There's not even a warning.

---

The more interesting fact is that the escaped `\?` can be used the same as `?` in some other languages as well. I tested in Lua/Ruby, and it's also true even though I didn't find this documented.

Comment: I'm not sure about other compilers, but `gcc` ignores digraphs and trigraphs by default.

Comment: @devnull True, I said the same thing in my own answer. :)

Comment: I saw that later, and have commented about it.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2393557/2235132) answer: `This is why the escape sequence '\?' is recognized (as a simple question mark - though presumably that is '??/?').`

Answer (score 49):

> Why is `\?` one of the escape sequence characters?

Because it is special. The answer leads to [Trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), and the C/C++ preprocessor replaces the following three-character sequences with the corresponding single character. (C11 §5.2.1.1 and C++11 §2.3)

```
Trigraph:       ??(  ??)  ??<  ??>  ??=  ??/  ??'  ??!  ??-
Replacement:      [    ]    {    }    #    \    ^    |    ~
```

A trigraph is nearly useless now, and it is mainly used for obfuscation purposes. Some examples can be seen in [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/).

GCC doesn't support trigraph by default and will warn you if there's a trigraph in the code, unless the option `-trigraphs`[3](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html) is enabled. Under the `-trigraphs` option, the second `\?` is useful in the following example:

```
printf("\?\?!\n");
```

Output would be `|` if `?` is not escaped.

For more information on trigraphs, see *[Cryptic line "??!??!" in legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718286/cryptic-line-in-legacy-code)*

---

> Why does non-escaping `?` work fine. There's not even a warning.

Because `?`(and double quote `"`) can be represented by themselves by the standard:

> #### C11 §6.4.4.4 *Character constants* Section 4
>
> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable either by themselves or by the escape sequences `\"` and `\?`, respectively, but the single-quote `'` and the backslash `\` shall be represented, respectively, by the escape sequences `\'` and `\\`.

Similar in C++:

> #### C++11 §2.13.2 *Character literals* Section 3
>
> Certain nongraphic characters, the single quote `’`, the double quote `"`, the question mark `?`, and the backslash `\`, can be represented according to Table 6. The double quote `"` and the question mark `?`, can be represented as themselves or by the escape sequences `\"` and `\?` respectively, but the single quote `’` and the backslash `\` shall be represented by the escape sequences `\’` and `\\` respectively. If the character following a backslash is not one of those specified, the behavior is undefined. An escape sequence specifies a single character.

Comment: The line: `For example, gcc doesn't support trigraph by default, unless the option -trigraphs is enabled. Under such options, \? is useful in some cases:` is **misleading**.  It seems to say that even if you don't use the `-trigraphs` option, gcc would interpret `??!` as a `|`.

Comment: @devnull: Many people disable gnu language variants with things like `-std=c++98` or `-std=c99` so trigraph support being enabled is quite common.

Comment: How can the double quote `"` represented by itself? Without escaping how can one type double quote in the middle of the string?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The standard isn't clear on that. I think `"` can't be used inside string literal, but you can use it in single quotes as `'"'` or `'\"'`, but `'''` is invalid, you must use `'\''`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The standard is clear: A **character constant** can be an escape sequence or "any member of the source character set except the single-quote ', backslash \, or new-line character".  A character of a **string literal** can be an escape sequence or "any member of the source character set except the double-quote ", backslash \, or new-line character".

Comment: I don't think trigraphs are just "nearly useless now".  By my understanding, efforts to find any use of trigraphs in production code failed to find *any* deliberate use outside of compiler test suites, demonstrations of how trigraphs work, etc.  That sounds like a more accurate (maybe less diplomatic) statement would be "a feature that was never really useful and should never have been in the language in the first place".

Comment: Thanks for pointing the standards, took me a few hours to figure out why a std::string "\'" (backslash followed by single quote) returned a single quote and not the backslash to ... I just needed to escape both std::string "\\\'"

Comment: Late update: worth to mention that C++17 finally removed trigraphs entirely (see C.4.1 5.2; apart from, they aren't mentioned before anywhere any more, afterwards, only references to removal).

Comment: @devnull Don't understand your comment. The statement is absolutely clear. It says that trigraphs are not supported unless `-trigraphs` is used. What is misleading about that? The next sentence can't "undo" what the previous sentence has already defined.