# What does mean \? escape in C grammar?

Tags: c, escaping, constants, literals, bnf

I was reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhae3sw.aspx) and found the escape `\?`. What does means exactly this escape? the literal `?` inside a string(I still can't see a reason) or is this a BNF grammar rule which I don't know about?

Comment: Read [Why is “\?” an escape sequence in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374878/why-is-an-escape-sequence-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It specifies a literal question mark. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs

The backslash is used as a marker character to tell the compiler/interpreter that the next character has some special meaning. What that next character means is up to the implementation. For example C-style languages use `\n` to mean newline and `\t` to mean tab.

The use of the word "escape" really means to temporarily escape out of parsing the text and into a another mode where the subsequent character is treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in a feature called [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), it specifies a **question mark**. Using this you can write three-character sequence starting with question marks to substitute another character

From C11

> **C11 §6.4.4.4 Character constants Section 4**
>
> The double-quote " and question-mark ? are representable either by
>   themselves or by the escape sequences \" and \?, respectively, but the
>   single-quote ' and the backslash \ shall be represented, respectively,
>   by the escape sequences \' and \.

Comment: I think you mean C11 edit it I remove downvote (wasn't me, btw)

Comment: @Jack:- That was a typo. Updated that! Thanks