# Strange behaviour of visual studio 2008 with escape sequence

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, trigraphs

Regarding C programming language, the descriptions of escape sequence does not resolve the output of following line in visual studio 2008.

```
char * str = "??/abc";
printf( "%s", str );
```

it prints only "bc".
Checking the memory pointed by str, we can find that `"??/a"` is working as `"\a"`

Searching on google we can't find anything related to `"??/"` being treated as backslash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "\?" an escape sequence in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374878/why-is-an-escape-sequence-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on AProgrammer's comment, C defines a set of trigraphs for people whose keyboards are missing certain characters.  These begin with '??', followed by another character.  In particular, '??/' is the trigraph for '\'.

This translation is done very early on in the complilation process, so the compiler just sees '\a'.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe(v=vs.90).aspx)